# Canvas.drawText | Перенос строк | JAVA

Tags: java, android

Как сделать перенос строк при отрисовки текста? Написал функцию, которая изменяет размер, если длина текста больше ширина экрана, но это не то.

```
public int detectFontSize(String text, int size, int widthViewport){
    Paint mp = new Paint();
    mp.setAntiAlias(true);
    mp.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mp.setTextSize(size);

    mp.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), mTextBoundRect);
    float textWidth = mp.measureText(text);

    int r = 0;
    if(textWidth >= widthViewport){
        r = detectFontSize(text, size - 1, widthViewport);
    } else r = size;
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, ответа тут я не получу. Решил проблему, написав свою функцию.

```
public void printDescription(Canvas linkCanvas, String text, Bitmap selectedImage) {
    String[] desc = text.split(" "); //Можно изменить сепаратор, если того требует задача
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Paint alertText = new Paint();
        alertText.setAntiAlias(true);
        alertText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        alertText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        alertText.setTextSize(24);

        int active = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < desc.length; i++) {
            if(arr.isEmpty()){
                arr.add("");
                active = 0;
            }

            arr.set(active, arr.get(active) + desc[i] + " ");

            alertText.getTextBounds(arr.get(active), 0, arr.get(active).length(), mTextBoundRect);
            float width = alertText.measureText(arr.get(active));

            if (width + 150 > linkCanvas.getWidth()) {
                arr.add("");
                active++;
            }
        }

        float fixOffset = 0;

        float heightAlertBlock = (alertText.getTextSize() + 25f) * arr.size();
        float widthAlertBlock = selectedImage.getWidth();
        float[] centerAlertBlock = new float[]{widthAlertBlock / 2, heightAlertBlock / 2};

        fixOffset = heightAlertBlock / arr.size();

        printAlertBlock(linkCanvas, heightAlertBlock, widthAlertBlock, centerAlertBlock, selectedImage);

        float start = selectedImage.getHeight() - heightAlertBlock;

        float lastElement = selectedImage.getHeight() - heightAlertBlock + 25;

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
            alertText.getTextBounds(arr.get(i), 0, arr.get(i).length(), mTextBoundRect);
            float width = alertText.measureText(arr.get(i));

            linkCanvas.drawText(arr.get(i), centerAlertBlock[0] - width/2, lastElement + alertText.getTextSize()/2, alertText);

            lastElement += fixOffset;
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Возникла проблема! Повторите попытку позже.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, что кому-то помог этим кодом.

**UPD**: я новичок в JAVA, поэтому не удивляйтесь, если увидели что-то несуразное.

Comment: На самом деле надежный алгоритм переноса слов не такая простая штука, можете попробовать глянуть внутри класса TextView. Он много чего еще делает, потому в нем аж 12к строк, но можно поискать в нем решение это задачи